# Integrating With Respect To $x$

Tags: calculus, integration, notation, indefinite-integrals, differential

Suppose I have the first derivative of the function $y$, $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} = g(x)$. Furthermore, suppose I want to obtain the function $y$ by integrating with respect to $x$:

$\displaystyle \int \frac{dy}{dx} dx = \int g(x) ~dx$

Now, I know the result is

$y = G(x) + c$.

However, I would like to know what happens in between these steps. My question is, how does $\displaystyle \int \frac{dy}{dx} dx$ become $y$. Is it due to the fact that $\displaystyle \frac{dy}{dx} dx$ is defined as $dy$, from which I make the substitution so that the integral would be

$\displaystyle \int \frac{dy}{dx} dx = \int g(x) ~dx$

(substitution)

$\displaystyle \int dy = \int g(x) ~dx$,

which we integrate to get $y = G(x) + c$

Or does it have to do something with the chain rule?

PS Sorry if my notation is ambiguous or incorrect, I am just trying to be as generalized as possible.

Comment: Search "Fundamental Theorem of the Calculus".

Comment: It's just notation. $\int (\dots) \,dx$ (without limits on the integral sign, i.e., not $\int_a^b$) by definition means "antiderivative". And since $dy/dx$ is the derivative of $y$, its antiderivative is of course $y$.

Comment: So, it would not be correct to use the differential of $y$, $dy = \frac{dy}{dx} dx$?

Comment: If it helps you to think about it that way, yes, it is perfectly fine to use the differential.  Yet, I'm pretty sure that it would end up being extraneous reasoning, as your knowledge of $\int g(x) \,dx = G(x) + c$ relies on the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which already states that $\int \frac{dy(x)}{dx}dx = y(x)+C$